# Yii2: GridView, Why some data-key returns id and others returns object?

Tags: gridview, yii

I have been making making a code which would get the data values for each column row using `CheckboxColumn` class. All of them have returned the object model as value but one of the grid i just added is returning the id model instead of object like others do..

the code is like this:

```
<?= GridView::widget([
    'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
    'filterModel' => $searchModel,
    'tableOptions'=>[
        'class'=>'table table-striped table-bordered table-hover',
        'data'=>[
            'selector'=>'parametros'
        ]
    ],
    'columns' => [
        ['class' => 'yii\grid\SerialColumn'],

        'liminf',
        'limsup',
        'departamento.nombre',
        'decreto.nombre',
        'tipo.nombre',
        'subTipo.nombre',
        'caracterizacion.nombre',
        'rama.nombre',  
        [
            'class' => 'yii\grid\CheckboxColumn'
        ],
    ],
]); ?>
```

the other grids that return the objects have the same code structure.. nothing different.. not even in models. search model code is like this:

```
class LimitesSearch extends Limites
{
    public $departamento, $decreto, $tipo, $subTipo, $caracterizacion, $rama;

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function rules()
    {
        return [
            [['id', 'Departamento_id', 'Decreto_id', 'Caracterizacion_id'], 'integer'],
            [['Tipo_id', 'SubTipo_id', 'Rama_id'], 'each', 'rule'=>['integer']],
            [['liminf', 'limsup'], 'number'],
            [['rama','caracterizacion','subTipo','tipo','decreto','departamento','existente'], 'safe'],
        ];
    }

    /**
     * @inheritdoc
     */
    public function scenarios()
    {
        // bypass scenarios() implementation in the parent class
        return Model::scenarios();
    }

    /**
     * Creates data provider instance with search query applied
     *
     * @param array $params
     *
     * @return ActiveDataProvider
     */
    public function search($params)
    {
        $query = Limites::find();

        $query->joinWith(['departamento', 'decreto', 'tipo', 'subTipo', 'caracterizacion', 'rama']);

        $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
            'query' => $query,
        ]);

        $this->load($params);

        if (!$this->validate()) {
            // uncomment the following line if you do not want to return any records when validation fails
            // $query->where('0=1');
            return $dataProvider;
        }

        $query->andFilterWhere([
            'id' => $this->id,
            'liminf' => $this->liminf,
            'limsup' => $this->limsup,
            'Departamento_id' => $this->Departamento_id,
            'Decreto_id' => $this->Decreto_id,
            'Tipo_id' => $this->Tipo_id,
            'SubTipo_id' => $this->SubTipo_id,
            'Caracterizacion_id' => $this->Caracterizacion_id,
            'Rama_id' => $this->Rama_id,
        ]);

        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'existente', $this->existente]);
        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'departamento.nombre', $this->departamento]);
        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'decreto.nombre', $this->decreto]);
        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'tipo.nombre', $this->tipo]);
        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'subTipo.nombre', $this->subTipo]);
        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'caracterizacion.nombre', $this->caracterizacion]);
        $query->andFilterWhere(['like', 'rama.nombre', $this->rama]);

        return $dataProvider;
    }
}
```

and controller/function:

```
public function actionSelect()
{
    if(Yii::$app->user->can('limites-index'))
    {    
        $searchModel = new LimitesSearch();
        $dataProvider = $searchModel->search(['LimitesSearch'=>Yii::$app->request->queryParams]);
        return $this->renderAjax('select', [
            'searchModel' => $searchModel,
            'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        ]);
    }
}
```

***PS:*** i have noticed that only grids that has `dataProvider` from relational table models are returning the objects and this one, which is not actually a relational table model just returns the id.. why this happens?.. no idea, maybe i could just fix this by adding a `CheckboxColumn` option function.. but i would like to know why this happens

***Edit:***
This is what i want to get.. this come from relational table models

```
<tr data-key="{&quot;Decreto_id&quot;:1,&quot;Tipo_id&quot;:3}"><td>Normas Sanitarias de Calidad del Agua Potable</td><td>Capitulo 2 Aspectos Microbiologicos</td><td><input name="selection[]" value="{&quot;Decreto_id&quot;:1,&quot;Tipo_id&quot;:3}" type="checkbox"></td></tr>
<tr data-key="{&quot;Decreto_id&quot;:1,&quot;Tipo_id&quot;:4}"><td>Normas Sanitarias de Calidad del Agua Potable</td><td>Capitulo 3 - Aspectos organolépticos, físi...</td><td><input name="selection[]" value="{&quot;Decreto_id&quot;:1,&quot;Tipo_id&quot;:4}" type="checkbox"></td></tr>
<tr data-key="{&quot;Decreto_id&quot;:1,&quot;Tipo_id&quot;:5}"><td>Normas Sanitarias de Calidad del Agua Potable</td><td>Capitulo 4 - Los aspectos radiactivos</td><td><input name="selection[]" value="{&quot;Decreto_id&quot;:1,&quot;Tipo_id&quot;:5}" type="checkbox"></td></tr>
```

but this is what i get from the table i am rendering from a non-relational table model

```
<tr data-key="1104"><td>1</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>Agua</td><td>Normas Sanitarias de Calidad del Agua Potable</td><td>Capitulo 2 Aspectos Microbiologicos</td><td>Articulos 8, 9,10,11,12,13</td><td>Organismos coliformes</td><td>NULL</td><td><input name="selection[]" value="1104" type="checkbox"></td></tr>
<tr data-key="1105"><td>2</td><td>0</td><td>5</td><td>Agua</td><td>Normas Sanitarias de Calidad del Agua Potable</td><td>Capitulo 2 Aspectos Microbiologicos</td><td>Articulos 8, 9,10,11,12,13</td><td>Organismos coliformes Totales</td><td>NULL</td><td><input name="selection[]" value="1105" type="checkbox"></td></tr>
<tr data-key="1106"><td>3</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>Agua</td><td>Normas Sanitarias de Calidad del Agua Potable</td><td>Capitulo 2 Aspectos Microbiologicos</td><td>Articulos 8, 9,10,11,12,13</td><td>Examen Virus</td><td>NULL</td><td><input name="selection[]" value="1106" type="checkbox"></td></tr>
<tr data-key="1107"><td>4</td><td>0</td><td>0</td><td>Agua</td><td>Normas Sanitarias de Calidad del Agua Potable</td><td>Capitulo 2 Aspectos Microbiologicos</td><td>Articulos 8, 9,10,11,12,13</td><td>Examen de Bacterias</td><td>NULL</td><td><input name="selection[]" value="1107" type="checkbox"></td></tr>
```

as you can see. the first table one in checkbox values and `data-key` values have `JSON` objects.. but in the second one just have the id of the row

Comment: Please explain better,  use samples

Comment: @scaisEdge i have added the rendered tables for examples

Comment: Plaese show the controller/action related and (if any) the relations that you mention..

Comment: @scaisEdge i have added the controller/action and changed the model to the modelSearch just like the action requests it

Comment: Please show all the Limites  model code i need check a few things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`data-key` data attribute holds the primary key value of record that each row of GridView related to.

In case of single primary key it's a simple number, in case of composite primary key (used in tables with many-to-many relations for example) it's object because otherwise there is no way to resolve it. In both cases this is still a string in DOM because it's attribute value.

It's used in [yii.gridView.js](https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/assets/yii.gridView.js) for getting selected rows with [yii\grid\CheckboxColumn](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-grid-checkboxcolumn.html):

```
getSelectedRows: function () {
    var $grid = $(this);
    var data = gridData[$grid.attr('id')];
    var keys = [];
    if (data.selectionColumn) {
        $grid.find("input[name='" + data.selectionColumn + "']:checked").each(function () {
            keys.push($(this).parent().closest('tr').data('key'));
        });
    }
    return keys;
},
```

This method is called when you get selected rows in Javascript like that:

```
$('#grid').yiiGridView('getSelectedRows');
```

Comment: oh well, i didn't know that.. looks like i would have to create a new data for all grids to show the model object.. regardless of relationship, thanks for this information.. it was very useful

Comment: but it's weird, the value of the `data-key` is always equals to real value minus 1, how can I fixed this? 

Screenshot: https://i.imgur.com/Xr1U6Ez.jpg